# App Store Connect App Units Metrics - Missing Current Downloads

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I published my first app on the App Store and am a little confused about some of the metrics.

**I want to know: right now, how many people have my app installed?**

When I look to the App Units for *this week* (which I understand to be `Each app purchase on a device with iOS 8 or tvOS 9, or later.`) I see 1 unit. When I expand the date range to *two months*, I get 110 units.

Does this mean there are currently 110 unique devices with my app installed and this week I only have one new install?

Why does it say -67% on the 1 app unit over the last 7 days? What is this % standing for?

Answer (score 0):

App units represent installs. So, if your units are at 110 that means AT LEAST 110 people installed your app. However, it may be slightly higher as not all users share that information. (I've got a new app on the app store myself, and I must confess I know more about the coding side of things than how all the metrics are calculated.)